# Nil-coalescing to provide default values in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

Previously (i.e. prior to Swift 1.2) I've used code like this:

```
self.name = jsonDictionary["name"] as? String ?? "default name string here"
```

I've found this to be a readable but concise way of:

- getting a value from a dictionary
- checking it's of the type I'm expecting
- assigning a default value

However in Swift 1.2, I get this compiler error:

```
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
```

I can't see anything in the Xcode 6.3 release notes or the Apple Swift Blog about this.

Answer (score 5):

Seems you now have to use brackets:

```
self.name = (jsonDictionary["name"] as? String) ?? "default name string here"
```

Comment: As of Xcode 6.3 beta 2 (released 23/2/2015), this is fixed - see bottom page 7 of Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf